# Problem on property of complex polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Given that, the polynomial $f(z) = z+a_2 z^2 + \ldots + a_n z^n$ is one-to-one from the open unit disc $D$ to $\mathbb{C}$. I have to show that $|na_n|\leq 1$.

I have tried to show this by contradiction : Here, $f'(z)$ does not have any zero in $D$. Taking $g(z) = na_n z^{n-1}$, I tried to use the inequality $n|a_n|>1$ to get that $|f'-g| < |f'| + |g|$. If it were true, I could use Rouche's Theorem to get a contradiction.

But I am not being able to prove any useful inequality here. Can anybody please help me in this ??

Any comment is welcome. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: use the fundamental theorem of algebra to show that if a polynomial $p(z)=\sum_{i=0}^n c_i z^i$ has no zeros in $D$ then $|c_0|\geq  |c_n|$.